# gevent-socketio send message from thread

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

I would like to use gevent-socketio to send messages from a worker thread and update all connected clients on the status of the job.

I tried this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    send(message, broadcast=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def ping_thread():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'Pinging'
        send('ping')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=ping_thread)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    socketio.run(app)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

How do I send messages from a function that doesn't have the `@socketio.on()` decorator? Can I use `gevent` directly to send messages to `socketio`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this section of the documentation](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#broadcasting):

> Sometimes the server needs to be the originator of a message. This can be useful to send a notification to clients of an event that originated in the server. The socketio.send() and socketio.emit() methods can be used to broadcast to all connected clients:

```
def some_function():
    socketio.emit('some event', {'data': 42})
```

This `emit` is not from `from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, send`, but instead called on your `socketio` variable from `socketio = SocketIO(app)`. Had you done `socketio_connection = SocketIO(app)`, then you'd be calling `socketio_connection.emit()` to broadcast your data.

Comment: I actually didn't see that section in the documentation (d'oh!). But that is exactly what I tried to do anyway (see my code above) and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You're calling `emit`, but the link says to call `socketio.emit`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Celeo. I've updated my post to include more of my code. As you can see, I am importing `emit` and `send` directly, not `socketio`, so that's not my problem.