# Using Popen in a thread blocks every incoming Flask-SocketIO request

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, pipe, popen

I have the following situation:
I receive a request on a socketio server. I answer it (socket.emit(..)) and **then** start something with heavy computation load **in another thread**.

If the heavy computation is caused by `subprocess.Popen` (using `subprocess.PIPE`) it totally blocks every incoming request as long as it is being executed although it happens in a separate thread.

No problem - in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python/4896288#4896288) it was suggested to asynchronously read the result of the subprocess with a buffer size of 1 so that between these reads other threads have the chance to do something. Unfortunately this did not help for me.

I also already [monkeypatched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581255/python-flask-socketio-send-message-from-thread-not-always-working%20monkeypatched) eventlet and that works fine - as long as I don't use `subprocess.Popen` with `subprocess.PIPE` in the thread.

In this code sample you can see that it only happens using `subprocess.Popen` with `subprocess.PIPE`. When uncommenting `#functionWithSimulatedHeavyLoad()` and instead comment `functionWithHeavyLoad()` everything works like charm.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

import time
from threading  import Thread

@socketio.on('client command')
def response(data, type = None, nonce = None):
    socketio.emit('client response', ['foo'])
    thread = Thread(target = testThreadFunction)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def testThreadFunction():
    #functionWithSimulatedHeavyLoad()
    functionWithHeavyLoad()

def functionWithSimulatedHeavyLoad():
    time.sleep(5)

def functionWithHeavyLoad():
    from datetime import datetime
    import subprocess
    import sys
    from queue import Queue, Empty

    ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

    def enqueueOutput(out, queue):
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            if line == '':
                break
            queue.put(line)
        out.close()

    # just anything that takes long to be computed
    shellCommand = 'find / test'

    p = subprocess.Popen(shellCommand, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)
    q = Queue()
    t = Thread(target = enqueueOutput, args = (p.stdout, q))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()

    text = ''

    while True:
        try:
            line = q.get_nowait()
            text += line
            print(line)
        except Empty:
            break

    socketio.emit('client response', {'text': text})

socketio.run(app)
```

The client receives the message 'foo' after the blocking work in the functionWithHeavyLoad() function is completed. It should receive the message earlier, though.

This sample can be copied and pasted in a .py file and the behavior can be instantly reproduced.

I am using Python 3.4.3, Flask 0.10.1, flask-socketio1.2, eventlet 0.17.4

**Update**

If I put this into the functionWithHeavyLoad function it actually works and everything's fine:

```
import shlex
shellCommand = shlex.split('find / test')

popen = subprocess.Popen(shellCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

lines_iterator = iter(popen.stdout.readline, b"")
for line in lines_iterator:
    print(line)
    eventlet.sleep()
```

The problem is: I used `find` for heavy load in order to make the sample for you more easily reproducable. However, in my code I actually use `tesseract "{0}" stdout -l deu` as the sell command. This (unlike `find`) still blocks everything. Is this rather a `tesseract` issue than eventlet? But still: how can this block if it happens in a separate thread where it reads line by line with context switch when `find` does not block?

Comment: your interpretation of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/4279) is incorrect. `bufsize=1` means *line-buffered* and it has no effect on other threads. More importantly, It is *pointless* to use `while True: q.get_nowait()`. There is no need to use nested threads here. Try: `text = os.fsdecode(subprocess.check_output("find / test".split(), stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL))` instead (the key here is to avoid inheriting standard streams from the parent). Does `eventlet.monkey_patch()` patches `time.sleep()`, `threading.Thread`? (if it does then you can't rely on the usual behavior).

Comment: If I use `recognizedText = os.fsdecode(subprocess.check_output(shellCommand, stdin=os.devnull, stderr=os.devnull))` instead of `Popen`, `q.get_nowait()` in a while-loop and threading like you said, during the whole process everything is blocked, just like before.

Comment: 1. `stdin=os.devnull` won't work (configure your system, to see errors), use `subprocess.DEVNULL` instead 2. if it blocks everything despite being called from `testThreadFunction()` that is running in a different thread then you should investigate what are the alternatives to `threading` + `subprocess` in `eventlet`.

Comment: *both* `tesseract` and `find` block (on `.readline()`). The difference is that `find` might flush its stdout buffer sooner. Try any command that doesn't flush its stdout buffer often, to see that it blocks e.g., `while[time.sleep(1)]: print` (python enables the block-buffering mode (in non-interactive mode) and therefore it won't flush the buffer on newline. Everything blocks until the buffer overflows (after ~4K lines in an hour). Either use real threads (not patched for eventlet) or use `subprocess` alternatives that expect to work with eventlet (IO is integrated with the event loop).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to this question I learned something new today. Eventlet does offer a greenlet friendly version of subprocess and its functions, but for some odd reason it does not monkey patch this module in the standard library.

Link to the eventlet implementation of subprocess: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/master/eventlet/green/subprocess.py

Looking at the eventlet [patcher](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/master/eventlet/patcher.py), the modules that are patched are os, select, socket, thread, time, MySQLdb, builtins and psycopg2. There is absolutely no reference to subprocess in the patcher.

The good news is that I was able to work with `Popen()` in an application very similar to yours, after I replaced:

```
import subprocess
```

with:

```
from eventlet.green import subprocess
```

But note that the currently released version of eventlet (0.17.4) does not support the `universal_newlines` option in `Popen`, you will get an error if you use it. Support for this option is in master (here is the [commit](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/commit/5a4a7ead2435025e2c727c902d7e985be0204417) that added the option). You will either have to remove that option from your call, or else install the master branch of eventlet direct from github.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked instantly. It's a little disappointing that they do not patch the subprocess module. That's what I was expecting.

Comment: Yeah, I plan to submit a patch to add subprocess into the patcher when I get a bit of free time.