# Python SocketIO message lost when sent to Frontend from Subprocess

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, subprocess

I want to start another python process from within my flask application. This process prints some feedback once and then. I then try to send this feedback to the frontend of my application using socketio. However, the messages sent from this subprocess never arrive.

The function that executes my program:

```
def executePY(cmd):
    popen = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line
    popen.stdout.close()
```

The function that calls the Execution and then waits for responses:

```
def test():
    for statement in executePY(['python3', '-u', 'bla.py']):
        send_to_frontend(statement)
```

The function sending the messages to the frontend:

```
def send_to_frontend(msg):
    print(msg) # The Message arrives here!
    socketio.emit('message', msg, namespace='/bla')
```

Receiving the messages in the frontend:

```
var namespace = '/editor';
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000' + namespace);

// Python Output
socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); // No Message here!
});
```

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify, when I simply call `send_to_frontend('test')` without starting a subprocess, everything works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

When searching for answers to this, i stumbled upon the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649180/4620643

following the approach of simply replacing

`import subprocess`

with

`from eventlet.green import subprocess`

fixed the issue.